# 2 Errors trying to insert data into a database using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm sorry this is probably a stupid question, but I'm new to this and I couldn't find an answer on google. This code is giving me two errors:

`Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Music Collection\submitmusic.php on line 27`

`Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Music Collection\submitmusic.php on line 29`

Not sure how to fix this please help me.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Music Collection </title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php
    $con = "mysql_connect ('localhost','root','','music')";
    // Check Connection
    if (mysql_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect: " . mysql_error();
    }
    else
    {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $artist = $_POST['artist'];
        $album = $_POST['album'];
        $location = $_POST['location'];
        $media = $_POST['media'];

        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO entries (Title, Artist, Album, Location, Media) VALUES ('$title','$artist','$album','$location','$media')");

        if (!mysql_query($con,$sql))
        {
            die ('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
        }
        else
        {
            echo "record added!";
        }
    }
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$con = mysql_connect ('localhost','root','','music');`

Comment: As Deepu states, the `$con` variable should represent a mysql connection, not a string. Get rid of the quotation marks.

Comment: also, remove the `mysql_query()` call in the `$sql = ...` line, in the next line you only use the query as a string.

Comment: `msql_*` functions are deprecated and ALWAYS sanitise input data!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the double quotes around:

```
$con = "mysql_connect ('localhost','root','','music')";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. only use mysqli_. mysql_ is deprecated and will probably removed from php soon
2. your connect is false. Should look like this:

   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","","music");

Answer (score 0):

You are also calling mysql_query twice, unless you want two inserts you probably want to do something like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO entries (Title, Artist, Album, Location, Media) VALUES ('$title','$artist','$album','$location','$media')");
if (!sql)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

change your statment to

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO entries (Title, Artist, Album, Location, Media) VALUES ('$title','$artist','$album','$location','$media')",$con);
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove double quote around:

```
$con = "mysql_connect ('localhost','root','','music')";
```

i.e

```
$con = mysql_connect ('localhost','root','','music');
```

And then change the following line

```
if (!mysql_query($con,$sql))
```

to

```
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
```

because mysql_query's first parameter needs to be sql query and second database identifier.

rest of the code is fine